# Obtener valores de _REQUEST con mismo nombre

Tags: php, requests

Tengo una URL con la siguiente información de ejemplo

> ...php?**1576568306143**=No&**1576568306143**=si&**1576568332721**=tres&**1576568332721**=cuatro

Al meter el **request** en una variable de la siguiente manera, esta solo guarda el último valor de cada uno:

- App::prePrint(); - Pinta el **array** completo y ordenado

```html
$request = _REQUEST();

App::prePrint($request)
```

```html
Array
(
    [1576568306143] => si
    [1576568332721] => cuatro
)
```

¿Cómo puedo capturar todos los valores, aún siendo repetidos sus nombres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las superglobales `$_REQUEST, $_GET, $_POST` son arrays como cualquier otro.

Por definición un array no puede tener la misma clave repetida, lo que ocurre en ese caso es que el array se queda con el valor de la última de esas claves. Para entenderlo mejor, tu URL estaría creando algo como esto:

```
$_REQUEST=array(
                    1576568306143=>"No",
                    1576568306143=>"si",
                    1576568332721=>"tres",
                    1576568332721=>"cuatro"
                );
```

Las claves `1576568306143` y `1576568332721` no subsisten duplicadas en el array por lo ya explicado.

La solución más idonéa, si fuera posible para tí, sería modificar la URL que es emitida, evitando repetir claves, algo así:

```
http://www.tu-archivo.php?r1=No&r2=si&r4=tres&r5=cuatro
```

Es sólo un ejemplo, pues dependiendo del contexto puedes enviar datos mejor organizados, puedes enviar al servidor incluso verdaderas estructuras de datos, arrays multidimensionales, etc.

Si no tienes opción de organizar mejor la URL tendrás que pasar por un proceso un poco complicado, bueno tampoco lo es tanto, pero no es tan seguro, sobre todo si la URL no es uniforme.

Ese proceso consistiría en:

1. Obtener el `QUERY_STRING` de la URL mediante `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`
2. Crear un array del mismo con `explode`, usando el separador `&`
3. Recorrer ese array y crear un array multidimensional donde la clave sería el dato de la izquierda y el valor el dato de la derecha usando como referencia el signo `=`

Sería un código como este. Aquí uso `parse_url` porque no estoy en un entorno de servidor. En su lugar usa `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` en el script.

```
$q=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
var_dump($q);
$urlParts=explode("&",$q);
$urlParts = array_map("trim", $urlParts);
foreach($urlParts as $currentPart)
{
    list($k, $v) = explode("=", $currentPart);
    $newArray[] = array($k=>$v);
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

La salida sería un array multidimensional como este:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1576568306143]=>
    string(2) "No"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [1576568306143]=>
    string(2) "si"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [1576568332721]=>
    string(4) "tres"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [1576568332721]=>
    string(6) "cuatro"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Haciendo uso de los corchetes.

Fíjate en esta URL:

```
http://localhost/stackoverflow/pelukosa/?id[]=1&id[]=3&id[]=8
```

Cuando es recibida por este código:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Se obtiene esta salida en pantalla:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 8
        )

)
```

Aunque siempre utilizo `id`, cada dato repetido se almacena en un array enumerado.